# Are the pseudo-class rules overwritten by parent tag?? [HTML/CSS]

Tags: html, css

So I am taking this course in web design, and I am learning about pseudo-classes. I have written the code exactly as instructed but the pseudo class settings don't go through. Is it because the links are in a p-tag? That does not make any sense to me, and it works in the course video, just not for me. What am I doing wrong?

I have written the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage with Style</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            a {

                text-decoration: none;

            }


            a:hover { <!-- pseudo class -->

                text-decoration: underline;

            }

            a:visited { <!--changes style after website has been visited once-->

                color:green;

            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div>

            <p> <a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a> </p>

            <p> <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Open Google in a new tab</a> </p>

        </div>



    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what actually happens? can you provide a screenshot of what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Comment syntax wrong

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage with Style</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            a {

                text-decoration: none;

            }


            a:hover { /*pseudo class*/

                text-decoration: underline;

            }

            a:visited { /*changes style after website has been visited once*/

                color:green;

            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div>

            <p> <a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a> </p>

            <p> <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Open Google in a new tab</a> </p>

        </div>



    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that I have to write it differently in the style section :) It works now!